# Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Я был оповещен товарищем по работе - Олегом, - который позвонил раньше обычного.

Приложение, выделенное с двух сторон тире, носит пояснительный характер, поэтому меня интересует только одно: на месте ли запятая?

Comment: "... меня интересует только одно: на месте ли запятая" --- Запятая-то на месте, но чтобы предложение было исправлено, придется расширить сферу Ваших интересов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Я был оповещен товарищем по работе — Олегом, который позвонил раньше обычного.**

Перед запятой второе тире опускается.

[§ 19 (пункт 10). Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

Примечание.
**Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:**
1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится **запятая:**
*Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки.*

Answer (score 0):

1-й вариант: "Я был оповещен товарищем по работе — Олегом, который позвонил раньше обычного".

Его недостаток: создается впечатление, что "который" относится к Олегу.

2-й вариант: "Я был оповещен товарищем по работе, Олегом, который позвонил раньше обычного".

Имя в качестве обособленного приложения обычно выделяется запятыми, а не тире. Оно носит пояснительный характер, но это не заставляет авторов употребить тире.

> 6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо уточняет-нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть, а зовут его): Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.); Отец мой, Клим Торсуев, известный мыловар, был человек тяжёлого характера (Ж. Г.); А братья Ани, Петя и Андрюша, гимназисты, дёргали отца сзади за фрак (Ч.); Четвёртый сын ещё совсем мальчик, Вася (Пауст.); У дверей, на солнышке, зажмурившись, лежала любимая борзая собака отца, Милка (Л. Т.) [см. § 23, п. 1].

[(§ 19. Обособленные приложения)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)